# How to conditionally check string in IF condition python

Tags: python, regex, if-statement

I am have a variable called vol_dev value will be like this (it can be any value out of these )

/dev/sda1
or
/dev/sdb
or
/dev/sdc like this , I need to perform set of action based on above values in if condition.

so I using re module to like below. the idea is to check if there is pattern like  sda1 in vol_dev or not. any other pattern other than sda1 in vol_dev I need to do different set of action.

```
vol_dev = res_vol['Volumes'][0]['Attachments'][0]['Device']    
if re.search(r'sda1', vol_dev):
   print(vol_dev)
```

How to specify NOT condition in search pattern ? i.e search other than sda1 in above if condition. The problem i need to decide based on pattern in vol_dev variable.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated

Comment: `if not re.search(r'sda1', vol_dev):`?

Comment: Just negate the condition, not the pattern

Comment: oh my bad, yep just negating the condition was good enough